# SQL Syntax error when running DELETE from Java

Tags: java, sql

I get error ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

```
String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM customer" +
"WHERE (fname = 'Fred' AND lname = 'Flintstone')" +
"OR (fname = 'Barney' AND lname = 'Rubble')";
System.out.println("Records deleted: "
+ stmt.executeUpdate(deleteSQL));
```

Comment: You need to put spaces between `customer` and `WHERE`.

Comment: No space between closing bracket and `OR`

Comment: +1 for the names used :p

Comment: You could have easily solved this problem yourself my merely examining `deleteSQL` with the debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM customer " +
"WHERE (fname = 'Fred' AND lname = 'Flintstone') " +
"OR (fname = 'Barney' AND lname = 'Rubble') ";
System.out.println("Records deleted: "
+ stmt.executeUpdate(deleteSQL));
```

The problem are the **missing spaces** while concatinating.

**Imagine the following:**

> "word" + "word2"

this would result  `"wordword2"`

**so it should be**

`"word" + " " + "word2"` **or** `"word "+ "word2"`

Comment: Jup. That was it :) +